# PHP can I copy a file outside the webfolder?

Tags: php, xampp

I am using XAMPP

The DocumentRoot is C:/xampp/htdocs

I want to upload files to C:/DATA/SLIDES

Is this possible (without changing Apache's default DocumentRoot).

I'd like to add its a FRESH install of XAMPP.

PHP INI files are the default settings. 
What changes do I need to make to PHP.INI to make this work?

Comment: Are you uploading with an HTML form?

Comment: Yes i have an HTML form created.

Comment: And do you want to use PHP to store that file upon successful form submission?

Comment: I would ideally like to copy a file to a directory called C:\DATA\SLIDES (which is not accessible via browser). This is a local directory on the host. Right now, I am uploading the file to C:\xampp\htdocs\folder and my code is working and I can see the files.

Comment: why downvote? I didn't realize that it was possible to copy out of DocumentRoot

Comment: If you had just changed where you wrote "c:\xampp\htdocs\folder" to "c:\data\slides" in your code, it would have worked. Then you would have realized there was no reason to ask a question about a nonexistant problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. PHP does not know or care about Apache's `DocumentRoot` setting. All that matters are OS-level file/directory permissions and any restrictions you've enabled in `php.ini`

Example:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
$destination = 'c:/DATA/SLIDES/' . $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destination);
```

Comment: what do I need to change in PHP.INI and how would I copy to C:\DATA\SLIDES

Comment: You do not need to change anything unless you already added restrictions. To copy to c:\DATA\SLIDES, `move_uploaded_file($source, 'c:\DATA\SLIDES\filename');`.